# jQuery animation smooth in Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, safari

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .divs
            {
                width:900px;
                height:599px;
                border:solid 1px gray; 
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
            }
            #div_1
            {
                background:#fff url('../photos/home/Jun112010_5456.jpg') top left no-repeat;
            }
            #div_2
            {
                background:#fff url('../photos/home/_FRI2911.jpg') top left no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div_2" class="divs"></div>
        <div id="div_1" class="divs"></div>
    </body>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../../site/c_side/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(function(){
            $("#div_1")
                .animate({
                    opacity : 0.0
                }, 1000 , function(){
                    $("#div_2").animate({
                        opacity : 0.0
                    }, 1000 )
                })
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

The opacity animation plays smoothly in Firefox and Chrome, but not safari 5?  Why so?  *I appreciate the help in advance.*

Comment: sorry, I meant Safari 5 haha... Yeah, it works fine with mine (Safari 5 on Windows XP)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but you might try [this jQuery plugin](http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/09/01/enhancing-jquerys-animate-function-to-automatically-use-css3-transitions/) that attempts to use browser-native (CSS3) animation for certain transitions (including opacity).

Answer (score 0):

No need to use float values for opacity, it seems rather smooth in Safari 5 on Mac, I have colored your boxes to demonstrate, look at: http://jsfiddle.net/Gkfzd/1/. Hope it helps!

Comment: Two ideas spring to mind: either your pictures' paths are not set properly or the pictures are too big and the animation is triggered before the images finish loading. I tested with these successfully: http://jsfiddle.net/Gkfzd/2/. Maybe use `setTimeout` and trigger the fading later or shrink the images...